Can not scatter properly procedural plant on targeted mesh
I have created a procedural plant using geo nodes that i would like to scatte on a mesh using particles system.
When i instance oject selecting the plant as a target, only the curve appears and not the leafs.
What should i do to proceed correctly and make everything appear?
thank you


blend file 

you should first provide a node tree that we can read.

sure, here a blender file so you can better see 

My first guess is Realize Instances.  I see one in your tree, but I haven't looked closely at what you're doing.

Of course you can scatter in geonodes as well

@AllenSimpson You do realize the question already had an accepted answer before you commented and yes, Realize Instances was the issue ;)

@GordonBrinkmann no, I hadn't refreshed the page, I think.  LOL

Your leaves are just instances, they have to be real geometry to be used in the particle system. Plug a Realize Instances node between the Join Geometry and the Group Output nodes.

